# Upload chosen file to a directory

Tags: java, swing, file-upload

I am beginner in java., I want to upload the chosen file into a folder D:\temp . 
I tried the following.,got the path..., just want to write the file to the folder D:\temp

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.show();
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
String path=fd.getDirectory()+fd.getFile();
```

please help.....

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Path src = Paths.get(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile());
final Path dst = Paths.get("D:\\tmp", nameOfDestinationFile);
Files.copy(src, dst);
```